# jQuery Plugin - passing and executing an arbitrary function

Tags: jquery, ajax, function, plugins, asynchronous

I am fairly new at JQ so any help on this appreciated, few remaining cranial follicles are being traumatized...

I have a simple jQuery plugin that uses Ajax to populate the #selector (UL) with results (as a series of ) using AppendTo. This is a cross-domain call so, as far as I can tell, only asych:true is supported.

The plugin works but I need to allow the user to hit the appended DOM items with arbitrary functions (i.e. functions determined by the plugin user like $(".foo").draggable() or whatever) and doing it outside of the plugin doesn't work because we are cross-domain and async.

I think I need to pass the arbitrary function to the plugin at run time but that is far as I can get. I have fiddled with delegate()/trigger() and bind(namespcae.bar) but have had no success so far...

How should this be handled?

The call looks like this:

```
        $(document).ready(
        function () {
            $('#targetDiv').myPlugin({ count: 10});
            //$(".foo").draggable(); // does not work, because we are async.
        });
```

The plugin looks like this:

```
    (function ($) {
    $.fn.myPlugin = function (options) {  
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: true, async: false }); // false doesn't work - cross domain  
    var defaults = {count: 5};  
    var options = $.extend(defaults, options);  
    return this.each(function () {  
    var obj = $(this);  
    $.ajax({  
        type: 'GET',  
        async: false,  
        dataType: 'json',  
        data: {},  
        url: 'http://someurl.com?callback=?&otherstuff=somedata',  
        success: function (data) {  
            $.each(data.results, function (i, item){  
               t = $(<LI class='foo'> + item.text </LI>').appendTo(obj);  
               // this works but may need any arbitrary jQuery.ui function  
               //t = $(item.text).appendTo(obj).draggable();  
               // maybe this but not sure how it should be done  
               //$(t).trigger(ArbitraryEventHandler); ???
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass a callback to your plugin. Something like:

```
$('#targetDiv').myPlugin({ count: 10, callback: function(element){
    element.draggable(); // Or whatever you want to do with your item
}});
```

Then call this callback in the ajax success for example:

```
    success: function (data) {  
        $.each(data.results, function (i, item){  
           t = $(<LI class='foo'> + item.text </LI>').appendTo(obj);  
           options.callback(t);
```

Comment: Thanks very much... looks like I came up with about the same answer (see below) although yours looks cleaner with the function directly in the call... thanks v much!

Answer (score 0):

this looks like a good case for using the new **[deferred object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)** in jQuery 1.5 (which `$.ajax()` can use behind the scenes. Basically, it allows you to queue up callbacks to be executed when your ajax call successfully completes (or to be called when it errors).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers, I want to look at 1.5 at some point and I'll defintely see if that works (sounds right) ... I came up with the following while someone else was posting essentially the same solution , but a little cleaner... problem solved thanks all

First, create the arbitrary function like this outside of the DocumentReady block:

```
function myArbitraryFunction(t) { // do some work...}
```

Then add an option to the plugin options:

```
var defaults =  {
    count: 5,
    itemFunction:null};
```

and then in the call to the plugin, this bit of wizardy ends up passing a Pointer to ArbitraryFunction as an option value

```
$("#targetDiv").myPlugin( { count: 10, itemFunction: function () { my ArbitraryFunction(t) }});
```

and then lastly in the ajax success code block:

```
success: function (data) {
    $.each(data.results, function(i, item){
        t = $(<LI class='foo'> + item.text </LI>').appendTo(obj);
        // here is the magic !!
        if(option.itemFunction != null){
             options.itemFunction(t)
        }
....
```

lots of pieces to wire up but so far it appears to work....